# Determining an adiabatic gas coefficient

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, adiabatic

Is it possible to determine the adiabatic gas coefficient of an ideal gas when measuring the pressure of the gas in an isothermal process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The adiabatic coefficient $\gamma=C_P/C_V$ involves the heat capacities, which are defined
$$
   C_P = \left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P, \quad
   C_V = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V
$$
In isothermal process of ideal gas $\Delta U = \Delta H = 0$, and
$$Q = - W = RT \ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}$$
These results are the same for *all* ideal gases, and as we see, they don't depend on the heat capacicities. Therefore, we cannot extract information about the heat capacities from an isothermal process.

But we can do that from an *isobaric* process. In this case
$$
   \Delta H = Q = C_P \Delta T\quad \Rightarrow C_P = \frac{Q}{\Delta T}
$$
By measuring the amount of heat we obtain $C_P$, then we can get $C_V$ from $C_V=C_P-R$. If the heat capacities depend on temperature we need to (i) conduct this process in small temperature steps ($\Delta T\to dT$) and (ii) and repeat it at various temperatures in order to get $C_P$ as a function of $T$